# Crash while monitoring a log file (C++)

Tags: c++, file, crash, wxwidgets, file-monitoring

I am reading a log file which is being written continuously by some installer process. However, in some cases I get a random crash with following reason:

```
Crash reason:  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ
```

I have a couple of questions regarding this-

1: If you see the following code, I am trying to handle any exceptions that occur while reading. So why is the EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION_READ not getting caught and the program crashes.

2: It looks like it is happening because the installer writes to the file at the same time when I am reading the file. wxTextFile does not allow me the mode in which to open the file. So, if I use some C function and open the file in READ_ONLY mode, can this crash still happen?

Following is my code:

```
wxTextFile file( wxT("C:\\logfile.log") );    
WriteLog(wxT("Will start monitoring log file."));

while(true)
{   
    if(file.Exists())
    {
        try
        {
            if(file.Open())
            {
                wxString str = file.GetLastLine();
                WriteLog(wxT("Got::")+str);
                file.Close();


            }
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            WriteLog(wxT("CRASH: something went wrong::MonitorLogFile()"));
        }
    }

    //Exit if needed

    Sleep(1500);
}
```

Comment: The exception is (apparently) not a C++ exception, but (again apparently) a lower level hardware exception. Possibly propagated as a Windows SEH exception. It looks similar.

Comment: Ok. Is there any way to catch it or allow my program to recover from it if it occurs?

Comment: "access violation read" strongly indicates reading (checking value of) memory via an invalid pointer. which means, a bug. fix the bug, e.g. by using C++ standard library containers instead of manual memory management (if that's so).

Comment: You could use wxMutex to lock the file before the GetLastLine() call and release it after. You need to do the same in the installer code that writes to the file. See http://fossies.org/dox/wxWidgets-3.0.0/classwxMutex.html

Answer (score 0):

I do believe in 14 days your problem is solved isn't it?

I have a feeling (I know little about wxWidgets) that your compiler is performing an address addition here

wxT("Got::")+str

try changing that to 2 real strings

is wxT() a macro call that resolves to L"" ? if so, then you got your problem and you shall modify the code to perform a string concat using a real string object (not a macro text) + the second string object, at this point you are using the + as an operator overload not as a sum of addresses as I suspect

Regards

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer but this is definitely not the problem here as I added that log file after I got the crash reports. Also, that is a valid concatenation statement in wxWidgets and I have been using that at many other places without a problem. Anyway, thank you for your time. I used standard C functions to open the file in read-only mode and haven't seen the problem since then. :)

Comment: glad to know, I don't know that wxt() is for, and now I know !